# remote ssh connection failed with this error message in output of vscode (I'm connecting from linux server 18 to mac using ssh extension)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server, openssh, vscode-remote

```
        [12:03:55.917] Log Level: 2
[12:03:55.919] remote-ssh@0.61.0
[12:03:55.919] darwin x64
[12:03:55.921] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+192.168.0.108", attempt 1
[12:03:55.921] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[12:03:55.921] "remote.SSH.sshPath": ssh
[12:03:55.921] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": /Users/apple/.ssh/config
[12:03:55.922] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[12:03:55.922] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": true
[12:03:55.922] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[12:03:55.922] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[12:03:55.922] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[12:03:55.922] "remote.SSH.maxReconnectionAttempts": 9007199254740991
[12:03:55.923] SSH Resolver called for host: 192.168.0.108
[12:03:55.923] Setting up SSH remote "192.168.0.108"
[12:03:55.926] Acquiring local install lock: 
/var/folders/8g/jfn_yxnn63j718q8_f2fkrw00000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-192.168.0.108- 
install.lock
[12:03:55.948] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/apple/Library/Application
```

Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-192.168.0.108-
940b5f4bb5fa47866a54529ed759d95d09ee80be-0.61.0/data.json
[12:03:55.952] Using commit id "940b5f4bb5fa47866a54529ed759d95d09ee80be" and quality
"stable" for server
[12:03:55.971] Install and start server if needed
[12:03:55.982] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[12:03:56.032] > OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

```
[12:03:56.035] Using SSH config file "/Users/apple/.ssh/config"
[12:03:56.036] askpass server listening on 
/var/folders/8g/jfn_yxnn63j718q8_f2fkrw00000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-
```

a053265c1873c60f803ede861fc6322c4ed520cd.sock
[12:03:56.037] Spawning local server with
{"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/8g/jfn_yxnn63j718q8_f2fkrw00000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-
220be0bb451b619d8ebcba60f7b13b9801f559f3.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-
D","50504","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","-

F","/Users/apple/.ssh/config","192.168.0.108"],"dataFilePath":"/Users/apple/Library/Application
Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-192.168.0.108-
940b5f4bb5fa47866a54529ed759d95d09ee80be-0.61.0/data.json"}
[12:03:56.037] Local server env:
{"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-
vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/local-
server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Users/apple/Desktop/Visual Studio
Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper.
(Renderer)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-
remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/askpass-
ssh-askpass-a053265c1873c60f803ede861fc6322c4ed520cd.sock"}
[12:03:56.041] Spawned 3077
[12:03:56.217] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 3078
[12:03:56.241] stderr> OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
[12:03:56.266] stderr> Connection reset by 192.168.0.108 port 22
[12:03:56.268] > local-server> ssh child died, shutting down
[12:03:56.275] Local server exit: 0
[12:03:56.275] Received install output: OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
Connection reset by 192.168.0.108 port 22

```
[12:03:56.276] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 
 2.7.3Connection reset by 192.168.0.108 port 22
[12:03:56.276] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[12:03:56.283] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh- 
    0.61.0/out/extension.js:1:82322)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode- 
    remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:1:78935)
    at Object.t.tryInstallWithLocalServer (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode- 
     remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:102434)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async /Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh- 
    0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:104499
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode- 
    remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:110308)
    at async /Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh- 
    0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:100987
    at async S (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh- 
     0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:97777)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode- 
     remote.remote-ssh-`0.61.0`/out/extension.js:127:100636)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh- 
     0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:108250)
    at async /Users/apple/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh- 
    0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:129627
    [12:03:56.289] ------
```

Comment: This post contains only code with no context, please add more context into your post.